# How to resolve [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified -Python while using PackerPy

Tags: python, python-unittest, packer

I am trying to use the Packerpy to validate a packer script, to do that I did this

```
  template = 'license-manager.json'
 t = open(template,'r')
 print(t.__sizeof__());
 with open(template, 'r') as f:
    response = PackerExecutable().validate(f.read())
```

It's giving me this error

```
192   
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/dmeena/Desktop/pythonProject1/venv/aws/python/Tests/Tes1.py", line 10, in <module>
        response = PackerExecutable().validate(f.read())
      File "C:\Users\dmeena\\Desktop\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\packerpy\packer.py", line 81, in validate
        return self.execute_cmd("validate", template, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\dmeena\Desktop\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\packerpy\packer.py", line 125, in execute_cmd
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE if is_json else None,
      File "C:\Users\dmeena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Users\dmeena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The Json file is in same folder as this python script and I am able to read and find the size of the file but when I try to pass it as a parameter to validate function , it's giving me that error
Let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reading the traceback properly.  It's not complaining about the JSON file.  It's saying that the "packer" command does not exist.  You must have `packer.exe` in the path, or in the same directory as your script, or pass its path to the `PackerExecutable` function.

Comment: Thanks  Tim  for the answer, Now I understand I need to first set up the the path for the packer.exe using packerExecutable. But I am unable to locate that executable

Comment: Oh I needed to download it separately, its working now ,Thanks for the help